# Ubuntu 22.04 - Camera Not Working After Updating UVC Driver

Tags: drivers, webcam

I'm facing a camera issue on my Linux system.

Recently, I decided to update my camera's UVC video driver as I thought it might improve its performance. I followed a guide I found online and executed a script that was supposed to do the job.

The script involved updating packages, installing essential tools for module compilation, downloading the kernel source, replacing the existing UVC driver with an updated version, and finally, loading the updated module. Everything seemed to run smoothly and there were no errors.

However, after the update, my camera is still not working. When I try to use it with applications like video conferencing or image capture software, it simply won't activate. I've tried restarting my system and checked that the camera is connected properly, but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

To give you more context, my Linux system is running on kernel version 5.19.0-50-generic, and I used the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential -y

cd ~
sudo apt-get source linux-hwe-5.19
cd ~/linux-hwe-5.19/drivers/media/usb/uvc
mv uvc_driver.c uvc_driver.old
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Giuliano69/uvc_driver-for-Quanta-HD-User-Facing-0x0408-0x4035-/main/uvc_driver.c
sudo make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
sudo reboot
```

I'm not entirely sure what could be causing this problem. I did some research and checked system logs, but I couldn't find any errors related to the UVC driver or the camera.

I wonder if there's a step I might have missed or if the updated driver is not fully compatible with my camera model. Another thought is whether there could be some permissions issue preventing my user from accessing the camera.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or knows a solution, I would be immensely grateful for your help. I'm eager to get my camera working again, and any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you open an issue with the GitHub project of the driver? The author of the driver may have a better idea of what is going on https://github.com/Giuliano69/uvc_driver-for-Quanta-HD-User-Facing-0x0408-0x4035-

Comment: Run the command `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo` and check if it works?

Comment: Was the camera working before? What is the make and model of the camera? You can also get the manufacturer or device id by running `lsusb` while the device is plugged in.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Anyone found the solution for this?

Comment: For me the problem was the shutter was closed. 
Please see this: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-in/inspiron-14-5410-2-in-1-laptop/inspiron-5410-2-in-1-setup-and-specifications/using-the-privacy-shutter?guid=guid-514df42a-261e-493a-9ddb-08f3d2e3b8ab&lang=en-us